# How can I mark a website as read?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

I am currently looking to rent a house, so I am looking at a lot of apartment listings. I would like to be able to mark a listing as "read" such that if I visit it again, there will be an indicator that this page has already "been dealt with".

I found an extension "Mark as Read" that seemed to do what I needed, but it seems to have been discontinued.

Is there any way I could achieve this?

Comment: Ctrl-click on it, then close tab

Comment: It's not a blue link that turns into purple that I want. The sites I use don't have this kind of link unfortunately, but rather images (like of appartments)

Comment: Why not ctrl-click on images? What is your target? Add page to history? Remove page from suggestions?

Comment: My target is to go to a listings website every day and ctrl-click all the listings that interest me. When I go to the detail page of a listing, and do something about it (either ignore it, call the owner, or send an email), I would like to "Mark the page as read" so that next time, if I click on the listing and go to the detail, it will show me that I have already done something about this website, therefore allowing me to not waste time by sending an email or calling to the same person again.

Comment: This sounds more like a specialized operation specifically for this website, doesn't it?

Comment: No, I don't just consult one listings website, but several. Therefore, the solution should be able to mark any page as "read"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently in need of this functionality yet again and with no solution matching my needs in sight, I decided to delve into the docs and solve my own problem.

---

## [Mark as Read (Google Chrome Extension)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mark-as-read/hiflhkmicfagennabmnfcnnlpkmidfjj)

Allows the user to tick off a website by clicking on the extension icon.

If the page is unchecked it will look like this:

[image: unchecked page]

If the page is checked it will look like this:

[image: checked page]

If you want to contribute or suggest changes, feel free to do so [at the GitHub repo](https://github.com/edoreld/mark-as-read).

Answer (score 2):

## Use FirstVisit extension

- Download it from my GitHub https://github.com/cyclopentan/cyclopentan.github.io/tree/master/firstVisit
- Choose any folder to install in, then unpack it
- Go to chrome://extensions/
- Enable developer mode [image: dev mode]
- Click to "Upload unpacked extension" [image: unpacked]
- Select folder [image: folder]

If you visited this page it will look like this
[image: visited]

If not, like this [image: not visited]

*Full disclosure: I am the author of this plugin.*

Comment: Is there a way to make it so marking a page as read is a manual action from the user rather than an automatic action from the extension?

Comment: @edoreld i coded it in 1 hour, and don't care about it)

Comment: @edoreld Its open source, maybe you/someone else can add it functionality

Comment: https://github.com/cyclopentan/cyclopentan.github.io/tree/master/firstVisit

Answer (score 1):

## Use Chrome's Bookmark Feature

Chrome displays a little star in the URL field for bookmarking. You can use that star to indicate whether you have read a URL. This does not require adding an extension.

### Mark a page as *read*

1. Press the star icon.
2. Add the bookmark to a dedicated folder called "Marked as Read" (or any other name you prefer).

[image: marking a page as read]

### Mark a page as *unread*

1. Press the star icon.
2. Click the Remove button.

[image: marking a page as unread]

### Is a page *read* or *unread*?

If the star icon is **filled-in**, it is *read*.

[image: example of read page]

If the star icon is **outlined**, it is *unread*.

[image: example of unread page]